# Download data option for customers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multi tenant Rails app where the data of a customer is separated with a global scope. Now I want to give the customers the option to download all their own data in a single download. What is the best way to achieve this? Is it best to output everything into a CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it into 1 csv file is going to likely cause you headaches.

I agree with Alex to do it as a background job if you go with CSV.

I will walk you through 2 approaches (CSV and Feed) and then you can choose what works for you.

1. CSV

Normally there are many tables that you want to export. If you put it all into one CSV file, it will be a bit messy of a file. 
Instead I would set a nightly process for each customer for each table. 
These generate CSVs for each customer for each table and stage them.

Finally for each customer I would bring those files together into a compressed file, and prep for delivery (Web download, FTP, Email etc)

The downside really is the lack of real time.

If you need real time (or if the data set is large), then you have to think about the impact this will have to your production database. It could cause serious performance degredation over time.

One option to get by this is to have read only replicated databases and you can deploy/utilize as needed.

1. Change Management

Instead of creating these ever-growing files every night, or on each request you can process data as it changes.

For example, if your customers really need to get this data, it could be for dropping in their database. I would move away from downloading CSV's or excel and offer an API.

When data changes come into your system, you notify interested components of the change. This way they do not have to go to the DB to get the changes. The API can have a pickup location that serves up the changed data whenever it exists.

We have used this mechanism in large scale, high volume environments with great success.

1. Push Notifications
   Finally, there are web hooks. Basically when changes you post the data to their web server.

I would suggest if you are going to go with the CSV route, you look at the long term read impacts. You may not need to make a change now, but you should have in your plan an item and solution ready.

Finally I would break the task into many small tasks over 1 long running.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. It will only be needed when a customer decides to stop being a customer of my app and wants to take his data with him, so it will (hopefully!) not being used very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a commonly used format for this. There is a good rails cast on how to achieve this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

From my experience I can advice you to implement it as a background scheduled process because  export could be expensive in resources and take long time to finish. After the task is finished you can email a user with the download link for example.